# Overleaf editor automatically inserts an inconvenient line break in the middle of a word or sentence after apostrophes and accents

Tags: line-breaking, accents, overleaf, apostrophe

I have a problem which I believe to be linked to the Overleaf editor. I am writing a document in book format, in French. As I usually write articles in English, I copy here the beginning of the preamble in case this helps find the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

In the beginning, everything worked fine as usual, when suddenly after about 8 pages into the first chapter, a weird behaviour appeared: whenever I type an apostrophe (') or accents over letters (e.g. è, é, ë or ê), the editor automatically inserts a line break before. For instance, the sentence "Son travail était qualifié d'extrême." would read:

> Son travail
>
> était qualifi
>
> é d
>
> 'extr
>
> ême.

As you can imagine, this is extremely annoying when writing a whole book, especially in French where accents and apostrophes are absolutely everywhere!
At first I wondered if this was a problem with my computer, but any other software I tried doesn't show that issue. I also tried removing `babel` and `fontenc` packages, but still encounter the same issue. Note that this does not occur all the time: perhaps one times out of 50, the sentence would not be cut. Also, when I start a new paragraph, often the problem does not show before I've written a few sentences. Could it be an overload problem? If so, what would be a solution to avoid having to write paragraphs of 2 sentences each?

I have looked on Google and Stack Exchange, to no avail. It would be really helpful to know that someone else has already faced a similar problem, and hopefully solved it!

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT 1: As suggested by @Rmano, I added \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} after \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, which is probably better in terms of handling french characters, but unfortunately the problem remains.

EDIT 2 (in response to @yo' from Overleaf): Most of my paragraphs (within a single line) have over 350 characters, and it turns out that smaller paragraphs do prevent the problem. This does suggest that the issue comes indeed from the bug mentioned by @yo'.

Comment: Editor issues like this are hard to diagnose (and even harder for us to resolve), but Overleaf appear to have an excellent customer support. Maybe they can help you. Contact them and explain the situation to them, include a link to one of you projects exhibiting the behaviour, so they can have a look.

Comment: Have you tried to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Comment: Hi, Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. Can you please check whether you have very long lines in the source code (more than 350 characters)? If so, then you probably bumped into a bug that we recently discovered; sorry for this. If you shorten the lines, it should help. If it does not, please get in touch with us at support@overleaf.com and we can have a look at the issue.

Comment: I am experiencing the problem with portuguese writing. It is really anoying. That was not happenging until a couple of days ago.

Comment: @yo' it seems the problem does come from that bug you mention (see EDIT#2). Is there anything we users can do to help document the issue?

Comment: I'd just avoid long lines. Most of my lines are between 70 and 80 characters long. A normal line break will be treated pretty much like a normal space, so there should be no problem breaking paragraphs or sentences into several lines in the source. Only if you leave a line completely blank will you get a new paragraph.

Comment: Hi @ClaireGuerin as moewe mentions, breaking the paragraph into lines of code e.g. by sentences should do the trick. (And for me personally, it makes the code super easy to navigate: you see very well where sentences begin and end, and you can easily rearrange the sentences. So I recommend doing this irrespective of the current bug which we develop.) Also thanks for the offer about the bug reporting; however, we seem to be aware of the causes and our devs are already looking into proper solutions. Still, the willingness to help is much appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a bug in third-party software, namely the Overleaf online text editor that can only be solved by the developers of that site.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when writing in Spanish. Even using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`package as @Rmano suggested. One solution I have been using to avoid this problem is directly write using escape characters:

```
á -> \'a
é -> \'e
í -> \'i
ó -> \'o
ú -> \'u
```

I know that this solution is very uncomfortable but the line break is more uncomfortable.